# How addSelect() Builder method works in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eager-loading

Say I have these models:

**User Model**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'User';

    protected $fillable =
    [
       'username', 'favoriteColor'
    ];          

    public function flights()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Flight');
    }
}
```

**Flight Model**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Flight extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'Flight';

    protected $fillable =
    [
       'flightName', 
    ];              
}
```

I'm trying to do something with eager loading, whenever I do this:

```
$usersWithFlights = User::with(['flights'])->get();
```

I get data like this: (Which if fine, is what I expect)

```
{
    "userID": 1,
    "favoriteColor": green
    "flights": 
    [
       {
           "flightID": 2240,
           "flightName" : "To Beijing fellas"
       },
       {
           "flightID": 4432,
           "flightName" : "To Russia fellas"
       },       
    ]
}
```

But then I want to add a column using a select raw like this: (Don't think about how silly the `1 as number` is, it's just for the sake of the example.

```
$usersWithFlights = User::with(['flights'])->addSelect(DB::raw('1 as number'))->get();
```

I get the data like this:

```
[
    {
        "userID": 1,
        "favoriteColor": green
        "flights": []
    }
]
```

**QUESTION**

Was the addSelect() method made for this kind of behaviour? If not are other work arounds in order to achieve this?

**NOTE**

I know I could add in the select method something like `Flights.*, Users.*` but I want to know if the addSelect method works that way

Answer (score 55):

If you need default values from select and add some extra, you can use this construction:

```
$usersWithFlights = User::with(['flights'])->select()->addSelect(DB::raw('1 as number'))->get();
```

Answer (score 9):

At first take a look at the `addSelect` method:

```
public function addSelect($column)
{
    $column = is_array($column) ? $column : func_get_args();
    $this->columns = array_merge((array) $this->columns, $column);
    return $this;
}
```

This just adds the column(s) by merging with existing selected columns. So, when you use something like this:

```
$usersWithFlights = User::with(['flights'])->addSelect(DB::raw('1 as number'))->get();
```

The query becomes `select 1 as number from flights` and since your relation depends on a column value in the parent query so without any real column value there are no related records retrived. To check the queries you may try something like this:

```
\DB::enableQueryLog();
$usersWithFlights = User::with(['flights'])->addSelect(DB::raw('1 as number'))->get();
dd(\DB::getQueryLog());
```

Also, if you use a real column name in add select and if you don't select the related column for example, if you use `addSelect('someString')` then you'll get no related records either because you've to also select the related column that makes the relation and in this case you may try something like this:

```
$usersWithFlights = User::with(['flights'])->addSelect(['id', 'someString']))->get();
```

### Test:

This is a test result of `DB::getQueryLog()` where I've used something similar but with different tables in my `DB` which is:

```
Post->with('comments')->addSelect(DB::raw('1 as number'))->get();
dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

### Result:

```
0 => array:3 [▼
  "query" => "select 1 as number from "posts""
  "bindings" => []
  "time" => 9.0
  ]
1 => array:3 [▼
  "query" => "select * from "comments" where "comments"."post_id" in (?)"
  "bindings" => array:1 [▼
    0 => null
  ]
  "time" => 1.0
]
```

### Update:

The `addSelect` method is usefull when you've a query object at hand with some selected fields and later you want to add more fields in the select list so an example could be like this:

```
$userWithFlights = User::with('flights')->select(['id', 'someColumn']);
// Some code ... 
if(SomeCondition) {
    // So, now the query will be something like this:
    // ->select(['id', 'someColumn', 'anotherField'])
    $userWithFlights->addSelect('anotherField');
}

$result =  $userWithFlights->get();
```

If you want to specify some fields to be selected then you may use `select($fieldsArray)` instead. You may also try something like this:

```
$userWithFlights = User::with('flights')->get(['id', 'someColumn']);
```

Also, you may try something like this:

```
$userWithFlights = User::with(['flights' => function($query) {
    $query->select('user_id', 'flight_title');
}])->get(['id', 'someColumn']);
```

Comment: Thanks for such an elaborated answer. Now I get tons of things. But how can I solve my problem? Should I have to call select method typing all fields?

Comment: Actually you can totaly avoid `addSelect`, it's useful when you have a seperate query object with selected fields and later you want to add more fields to be selected.

Comment: select() method would do it right. I guess that's my way

Comment: Yes, you can use `select('fieldName')` to specify fields but add select will merged new fields with pre-selected fields. Also, when using select(), must include the primary key that makes the relationship otherwise related records will not be loaded. Also, you may use `Flight::with('someRelation')->get(['id', 'someColumn'])`.

Comment: On Laravel 6, I'm finding that `addSelect()` is replacing the whole select list with the single column in the select terms instead of adding to them. I'm using `$hidden` to hide some very large columns, so maybe that is affecting it. But just pointing out this method is potentially not as robust as expected.